# Error loading TTF file - Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, truetype

I have created a android project with LibgdGdx where i create a AssetManager class, where I load all the assets I need, but when I run the project i have an error when a ttf file is loading. The code of the AssetManager:

```
 public AssetManager manager;

public AssetsManager(){

    manager = new AssetManager();
    loadAssets();
}


public void loadAssets(){
    loadTtf("assets/Birds.TTF"); 
}

void loadTtf(String path){
    FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
    manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, "assets/Birds.TTF", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter font = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    font.fontFileName = path;
    font.fontParameters.size = 20;
    manager.load(path , BitmapFont.class, font);
}
```

I try to load the ttf file through this code

`BitmapFont font = manager.manager.get("assets/Birds.TTF",BitmapFont.class);`

Part of the error I have:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: assets/Birds.TTF (Internal)
                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:579)
                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:380)
                                                               at com.poum.game.Main.render(Main.java:33)
                                                               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:459)
                                                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1649)
                                                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1354)
```

As i have said, the project is run on Android

Thank you for everything

Comment: where is your `Birds.TTF` file ? Is it in assets folder of android module ?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the assets folder of the android module

Answer (score 0):

```
String path="Birds.TTF";     //can be inside nested folder
String fileName = "Birds.TTF" ;   // it can be any name with extension, will use to load and retrieve
```

Load in this way :

```
manager=new AssetManager();
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".TTF", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter parms = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
parms.fontFileName = path;    // path of .TTF file where that exist 
parms.fontParameters.size = 20;
manager.load(fileName, BitmapFont.class, parms);   // fileName with extension, sameName will use to get from manager

manager.finishLoading();  //or use update() inside render() method
```

Retrieve font from `AssetManager`

```
BitmapFont font=manager.get(fileName,BitmapFont.class);
```

**EDIT**

From your screenshot, I got your file name `Birds.ttf` not `Birds.TTF`

so change

```
String path = "Birds.ttf";
String fileName = "Birds.ttf"
```

Android file-system is case sensitive.

Run Configuration for desktop module should be like this :

[image]

Comment: can you show your assets folder along with your resources by screenshot.