# libGDX: Long loading time with FreeTypeFontGenerator

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

I'm using this for creating a BitmapFont:

```
Public class MyBitmapFont implements Screen{

    public MyBitmapFont(){
    font = new BitmapFont();
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new          
    FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 10;
    font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    generator.dispose();
    }

}
```

When I'm using in another Screen `this.setScreen(new MyBitmapFont())` to switch in `MyBitmapFont` Screen it needs round about 3 seconds to load this Screen. Is there any efficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all, you're not creating `BitmapFont` from `FreeTypeFontGenerator`.

  Generate font from `FreeTypeFontGenerator` :

  ```
  BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
  ```

  instead of by using `BitmapFont` default constructor

  ```
  font = new BitmapFont();
  ```
- If you notice some delay, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33653328/3445320) `AssetManager` and load all your assets (texture, fonts, sound...)  asynchronously and get your resource form assetmanager whenever you needed.
  Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739232/3445320) that explain font loading to `AssetManager` using `.ttf` file.